# Why does Core data NSSet invert my array?

Tags: core-data, nsarray, nsset

I have an array of `segments` each has an array of `fighters` associated with it.

The relationship can be described thusly:

```
One `segment` can have many `fighters`
```

The objects are managed by core data.

When displayed in a table view each cell has two buttons so a user can pick a fighter from a seperate view controller; and it then when it returns it will update the segment fighter relationship.

Because the relationship of `segment.fighters` a non-mutable `NSSet`, I need to modify it so that;

If

1. User presses left button, this infers that the first object in the segment.fighter is being picked
2. User presses right button, it infers that the last object in the segment.fighter is being picked

When I come to Update the relationship, sometimes; depending on the sequence of buttons pressed by the user; the positions of the objects in the `NSSet` are inverted.

ie:

> Sometimes a fighter that should be at position 0 is swapped with a
>   fighter at position 1, when this should never happen.

My code is as follows;

```
NSArray *currentFighters = [[segment valueForKeyPath:@"fighters"] allObjects];

NSLog(@"----- current fighters ---- ");
for (FCFighter *fighter in currentFighters) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [fighter description]);
}

NSMutableArray *currentFightersMutable = [currentFighters mutableCopy];
[currentFightersMutable replaceObjectAtIndex:fighterIdx withObject:pickedFighter];
NSArray *updatedFighters = [currentFightersMutable copy];


NSLog(@"----- updated fighters ---- ");
for (FCFighter *fighter in updatedFighters) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [fighter description]);
}

[segment setFighters:[NSSet setWithArray:updatedFighters]];

NSLog(@"----- [segment fighters] ---- ");
for (FCFighter *fighter in [[segment valueForKeyPath:@"fighters"] allObjects]) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [fighter description]);
}
```

I am using a NSMutableArray so that I can replace the exact object in the array.

I can prove that it works via logs

```
Picked fighter - AJ Fonseca 
----- current fighters ---- 
AJ Matthews 
A Sol Kwon 
----- updated fighters ---- 
AJ Fonseca 
A Sol Kwon 
----- [segment fighters] ----   // NOTE it has swapped them, but why?
A Sol Kwon 
AJ Fonseca 
-[FCSegmentTableViewCell configureCellWithSegment:]
#0 -- A Sol Kwon 
#1 -- AJ Fonseca
```

However when it gets to segment fighters output, the fighters are swapped; but my question is --

Why does the NSSet invert my array?

Many thanks

Comment: Also, I only want to update the specific fighter within the given segment; not the entire array for speed purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `NSSet` is an unordered collection of objects. The property `allObjects` which you use returns an array, but as the documentation for this method states "The order of the objects in the array is undefined.".

Because of this, whenever you try and get an array out of your set, you could get a different order.

To make sure the orders don't change, you should either a) use an ordered relationship for the fighters - but not a good idea as `NSOrderedSet` is a mix between an array and a set. b) apply a sort to the array returned from `allObjects` so that the order is consistent. This is my preferred method.

Comment: I'll look into this, but I believe using the NSMutableSet may also work; but I'll try your idea too

Comment: An NSMutableSet is still an NSSet; and is still unordered.

Comment: Oh, ok. I will use a predicate to sort the array that is consistent

Comment: No, a predicate filters an array - a simple sort function on the name of the fighter should be enough.

Comment: But names can be duplicated. Sorting on the unique identifier or primary key isn't going to cut it either; so I'm thinking I might need another entity to house a segment's list of fighters; and this entity has a row id; but perhaps I overthink it

Comment: Not necessarily. If you want to have a property that you can use to define sort ordering that's an acceptable solution.

Comment: I've found from a video and another query that you can `Set the relationship type to ordered in the core data editor. This will mean that you now get an NSOrderedSet of objects`; I will review this

Comment: I already mentioned that in my answer, Performance wise, it's probably easier to manage your ordering yourself.

Comment: I ended up using NSOrderedSet after many headaches trying to do it myself.  Thank you.